# How to set many to many relation where for different relations status of entity might vary

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two entities Player and Game that are in many to many relation. I am developing my applicaton with EF core 2.1 so i had to set intermediate class and configure it using fluent api. I would like to have options that for every game, every player can decide if he will play, won't play or he not decided yet.
In the end i would like to display information about every game with three lists consisting of players based on their "are you playing?" choice. and i am not sure how i should store this information in database

Player class

```
public class Player
{
    public Player()
    {
        this.PlayerGames = new HashSet<PlayerGame>();
    }

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PlayerGame> PlayerGames { get; set; }
    .....
}
```

Game class

```
public class Game
{
    public Game()
    {
        this.PlayerGame = new HashSet<PlayerGame>();
    }
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PlayerGame> PlayerGames { get; set; }
}
```

PlayerGame class

```
public class PlayerGame
{
    public long PlayerId { get; set; }
    public Player Player { get; set; }
    public long GameId { get; set; }
    public Game Game { get; set; }
}
```

I came up with idea that i could add one column to PlayerGame intermediate table and store this information there. For example player John will play in Game A and B, but he won't play in game C.

So the intermediate table would look like:

```
_____________________________________
|PlayerId |GameId  | PlayerStatus    |
-------------------------------------
|JohnId   |GameAId | 1               |         1 - will play
|JohnId   |GameBId | 1               |         2 - won't play
|JohnId   |GameCId | 2               |         3 - not decided
```

Does this idea seem alright or do you have better alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what you're looking for, and for simplicity's sake, your choice of `PlayerStatus` will work just fine. Depending on what database you are using you can leverage a different data type for that table column to work more seamlessly with EF.

For example, in SQL Server you can use the `bit` data type and make it nullable so that null in your EF model you can simply use a `bool?`:

```
public class PlayerGame
{
    public bool? PlayerStatus { get; set; }
}
```

The potential values will look like this: 
1 - will play,
0 - won't play,
null - not decided

HTH